# How to return Observable boolean as service in angular

Tags: angular

I have a question about how to return observable in angular with filter and map and also takeUntil.

My code looks like this:

```
private _destroy: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  public getAllDefaultsSet(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.dataFacade.loadData();
    return this.dataFacade.currentData$.pipe(
      filter((data: Data) => !!data?.id),
      map((data: Data) => !!data?.default1 && !!data?.default2),
      takeUntil(this._destroy)
    );
  }
```

I want this method as a servcie, and will be used such as

```
this.dataService.getAllDefaultsSet.subscribe((result: boolean) => {
 some code

})
```

any solutions??

Comment: Could you point out the actual issue? Things I notice in the code above: getAllDefaultsSet misses the `()` in subscription line. Also takeUntil doesn't make really sense in a service, since a service has no lifecycle hook

Comment: can you give me more inforamtion, or edit code directly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a method you can use

`my.service.ts`

```js
    private _myData$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    
    public getAllDefaultsSet(): Observable<boolean>{
        //Your actions
        return this._myData$.pipe(/*...*/);
    }
```

`my.component.ts`

```js
    this.myService.getAllDefaultsSet().subscribe((val: boolean)=> {
        //...
    });
```

---

If you want to get rid of `()` like you did, you can use an attribute:

`my.service.ts`

```js
    private _myData$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    
    public getAllDefaultsSet = this._myData$.pipe(/*...*/);
```

`my.component.ts`

```js
    this.myService.getAllDefaultsSet.subscribe((val: boolean)=> {
        //...
    });
```

---

Then, if you want to get rid of `()` and still perform your action before returning it, you can use attribute getter:

`my.service.ts`

```js
    private _myData$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    
    public get getAllDefaultsSet(): Observable<boolean>{
        //Your actions
        return this._myData$.pipe(/*...*/);
    }
```

`my.component.ts`

```js
    this.myService.getAllDefaultsSet.subscribe((val: boolean)=> {
        //...
    });
```